# Update multiple columns of a data frame dynamically in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to update multiple columns of a data frame using `mutate_at` in `dplyr`. But, getting an error. Please help, here's my code.

```
library(dplyr) 

var1 <- "x9,x10,x11,x12" ## columns that I want to update
var2 <- "x8" ## column using which I want to update above columns
var3 <- unlist(strsplit(var1, split=","))

df <- structure(list(x8 = 1L, x9 = 0L, x10 = 0L, x11 = 0L, x12 = 
 1L), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.frame"), .internal.selfref = '<pointer: 
 0x5621075d0370>') 

# df
#     x8 x9 x10 x11 x12
# 1:  1  0   0   0   1  

# df_output
#     x8 x9 x10 x11 x12
# 1:  1  0   0   0   0 


df %>%  mutate_at(var3, ifelse(var2 == 1, 0, var3)) ## update all the columns in var3 to 0 where value of column var2 == 1
```

> Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") : #  object 'x9' of mode 'function' was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(var3), 
      ~ case_when(!! rlang::sym(var2) == 1 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ .)))
```

-output

```
#  x8 x9 x10 x11 x12
#1  1  0   0   0   0
```